# Query within a range on sort key within dynamodb

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query a dynamodb table with a given partition key and a range for the sort key but the API keeps throwing back the following error:

> Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException
>   KeyConditionExpressions must only contain one condition per key

Here is the C# code for creating the request:

```
var partitionKey = 10;
var from = DateTime.NowUtc.AddDays(-1);
var to = DateTime.NowUtc;

var queryRequest = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = _tableName,
    IndexName = "index",
    KeyConditionExpression = "#pkey = :v_pkey and #skey >= :v_from and #skey <= :v_to",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        {"#pkey", "PartitionKey"},
        {"#skey", "SortKey"}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        {":v_pkey", new AttributeValue { N = partitionKey.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }},
        {":v_from", new AttributeValue { N = new DateTimeOffset(from).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }},
        {":v_to", new AttributeValue { N = new DateTimeOffset(to).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }}
    },
    ScanIndexForward = true
};

AmazonDynamoDBClient client = CreateClient();
var queryResponse = client.Query(queryRequest);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the BETWEEN KeyConditionExpression operator like this:

```
var partitionKey = 10;
var from = DateTime.NowUtc.AddDays(-1);
var to = DateTime.NowUtc;

var queryRequest = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = _tableName,
    IndexName = "index",
    KeyConditionExpression = "#pkey = :v_pkey AND #skey BETWEEN :v_from AND :v_to",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        {"#pkey", "PartitionKey"},
        {"#skey", "SortKey"}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        {":v_pkey", new AttributeValue { N = partitionKey.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }},
        {":v_from", new AttributeValue { N = new DateTimeOffset(from).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }},
        {":v_to", new AttributeValue { N = new DateTimeOffset(to).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }}
    },
    ScanIndexForward = true
};

AmazonDynamoDBClient client = CreateClient();
var queryResponse = client.Query(queryRequest);
```

Comment: Nice one, works perfectly also found this in the depts of the documentation. Weirdly I'd just expected it to change itself instead of having to be so verbose and explicit.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is **inclusive** on both ends. My use case requires a condition like `#skey >= :v_min AND #skey < :v_max` instead. I had to query with `BETWEEN` and then discard results that have `#skey = :v_max` once DynamoDB returned.